# trend towards MVC as opposed to web forms in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know there will always be uses for both methodologies, but to those who work various contract jobs or attend conferences, do you see a trend towards MVC as being the preference for most ASP.net development.  I understand this will involve lots of opinion on if you prefer one method to the other, but was curious.

Thanks for insight you might have

I apologize if this question is out of scope for the discussion. I didn't think about that when I asked it to begin with. I'm doing some dev in both and was trying to get a better idea of direction to take.  No worries then if this question is deleted or just dies.

Comment: Both are good depending on their circumstance - this site isn't really the place for discussion of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people enjoy challenges, and Webforms can be very challenging for large scale applications. ;)

Some people prefer to take the path of least resistance.  MVC can often times be that.

Yes, it's new.  And as such, there's a certain amount of "oooh, shiny" mentality, but MVC really does bring a lot to the table that Webforms makes more difficult.  Webforms, however, still has the drag and drop features that many people crave.

Comment: The fact that people still seem to think ASP.NET MVC is still new is a bit sad...

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that I thought it was new, but more of a trend of direction the community is taking.

Comment: @Doozer1979 - Well, asp.net and C# were "new" until about 2005.  Basically, what that means is that the technology is not considered "mature".  I th ink with MVC3, it's finally at the "mature" point where existing features do not change radically in the next version.

Comment: I agree, and i didn't mean to sound as though i was criticising you, as that wasn't my intention. I've been interviewing a few candidates lately, and it was kind of depressing that only a couple of them were up to date on MVC. There are far too many people out there clinging on to Web Forms!

Answer (score 1):

I havn't been in the industry for very long, but from what I have noticed everyone seem to prefer MVC and all new projects we start are built using MVC3 :)